# Building google chart compliant json from php dynamically

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am trying to achieve something here, that is, constructing a google chart compliant JSON object from PHP. So far I have managed, with the help of some users here (Thank you guys) to build the columns dynamically, as shown on the php script below.

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Check if query GET parameters are defined

if (isset($_GET['date'])) {
    $parm = $_GET['date'];
    $sql = "SELECT
        DomesticInternational as 'DomesticInternational',  
        SUM(CASE WHEN (SalesYear='$parm') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Value'                   
        FROM 
        (   SELECT DomesticInternational,SalesYear
            FROM couponsummary 
            WHERE SalesYear='$parm'        
        )as Data 
        GROUP BY DomesticInternational";
}

// Run query, store in associative array

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $i = 0;
    foreach($row as $name => $val) {

        // We retrieve the mysqli field type, switch on them, and assign them to $type

        $finfo = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result, $i);
        switch ($finfo->type) {
        case 253:
            $type = 'string';
            break;

        case 246:
            $type = 'number';
            break;

        default:
            $type = 'string';
        }

        // Constructs the column array

        $array['data']['cols'][] = array(
            'label' => $name,
            'type' => $type
        );

        // Constructs the cells array

        $c[] = array(
            "v" => $val
        );

        // echo $row[(string)$name];

        $i++;

    }

    // Constructs the rows array

    $array['data']['rows'] = array(
        array(
            'c' => $c
        )
    );
}
else {
    echo "0 results";
};

// We echo the json and enforce a numeric check on the values

echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . json_encode($array, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK) . ')';
$conn->close(); //We close the database connection here
```

JSON Output is as follows :

```
{
   "data": {
      "cols": [
         {
            "label": "DomesticInternational",
            "type": "string"
         },
         {
            "label": "Value",
            "type": "number"
         }
      ],
      "rows": [
         {
            "c": [
               {
                  "v": "D"
               },
               {
                  "v": 57499
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

However, the query actually returns this :

```
+-----------------------+-------+
| DomesticInternational | Value |
+-----------------------+-------+
| D                     | 57499 |
| I                     | 24840 |
+-----------------------+-------+
```

Therefore in the JSON, instead of 1 c[array], there should be two of them, with 2 v{object} nested in them but basically the second row returned by the query is being skipped :/. I really don't know what to do and I'm pretty sure I'm not understanding basic principles of programming but please bear with me, I'm just starting to learn :) Please help guys. Thanks :)

Comment: you are doing **a single** call to `->fetch_assoc()` -> `$row = $result->fetch_assoc();`. You need to do that call in a loop, ie. `if ($result->num_rows > 0) { while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ... [rest of you code] ... } } else { ...  [rest of you code] ... } ` so that it returns all of your rows.

Comment: I did try that, problem now is that I got the following output : `{
data: {
cols: [
{
label: "DomesticInternational",
type: "string"
},
{
label: "Value",
type: "number"
},
{
label: "DomesticInternational",
type: "string"
},
{
label: "Value",
type: "number"
}
],
rows: [
{
c: [
{
v: "D"
},
{
v: 57499
},
{
v: "I"
},
{
v: 24840
}
]
}
]
}
}` There are two extra columns added in my cols[array]

Comment: Try wrapping your `$array['data']['cols'][] = array( 'label' => $name, 'type' => $type );` with a `if($i==0){...}` so that it only adds the `cols` on the first loop -> `if($i==0){$array['data']['cols'][] = array( 'label' => $name, 'type' => $type ); }`

Comment: Doesn't work...I end up having multiple cols[array] no matter how I put it :/ and as you can see I still need two c[arrays] since there are two rows :)